# Unresolved reference : recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm following this tutorial [RecyclerView in Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttIfesjYDQQ&list=PLUcsbZa0qzu3Mri2tL1FzZy-5SX75UJfb&index=9&t=371s)
and facing the ***Unresolved reference : recyclerview***  error.
I think there is some problem in gradle file but I'm not able to fig it out.please help .
complete gradle file as well as link to xml code is given below [xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLSdE.png)

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newsapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: please don't include code as images, just include it here as text. most likely the example is using synthetic imports, so just findViewById instead

Comment: @a_local_nobody i'm having error in              **recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)**

Comment: that doesn't help much, could you please edit your question to include the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is outdated. It uses synthetics, which is deprecated and can't be used anymore. Read here more about migrating from synthetics, or try to find a more recent tutorial:

[Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)